# Extend concrete slab on slope

Tags: concrete, slab

We have an existing concrete pad that is 18’ wide x 20’ long.  The slab is level but is built into a hillside so has poured concrete that goes from level at access point to about 2’ at rear.  We would like to extend the 20’ side to 24’ to accommodate tractor before finishing the garage.  [we know how to build the walls, roof, etc.] We have been told can drill into the 2’ tall concrete wall and insert rebar and dig footer and lay concrete block on exterior portion (none adjacent to existing slab), run rebar up through block and driven into ground, pour gravel in the new 4ish’ by 18’ section, and than pour concrete 6” slab level to existing slab and pour concrete to fill block. The new slab will be about 3ish foot height. So about another foot drop in elevation to stay level. On side with existing slab, concrete pour would include wall down to foundation matching up with existing (hopefully this makes sense).  My question:  does this sound like will be structurally sound to build enclosed garage walls on and not separate from existing slab?

I know the picture is not great but hope it helps.

[image: drawing of new slab next to old]

Comment: We do know need a bonding agent in the holes drilled in existing slab wall to bond the rebar to existing.

Comment: A drawing of the existing pad and what you know about the footing and the planned addition will help immensely in allowing people to follow your description. It doesn't have to be a fancy CAD drawing, a literal sketch on a napkin with some dimensions written on and indication of new vs old would do. You can just [edit] a picture of it into your question.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added elevations to your sketch.  Don't have to be actual elevations, could just be relative, i.e. call the lowest point zero, and go up from there.  Example, if the lowest point on your current sketch is at top right, that would be zero, and if the bottom right is 1' higher than that, it'd be +1.